# MP4 File Format Specification

Tags: format, mp4, specifications, iso

I am writing some code to parse MP4 files ...

Is there a free source to get documentation on the MP4 File Format Specification. So far I have only found an ISO document which I would need to purchase [ISO PDF](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=38538). Is MP4 Not an open standard ?

Comment: All ISO documentation is paid for, which is a huge rip-off by iso.org, as an entity supported by public funds.

Answer (score 59):

Here's the [specification of the ISO base format](https://web.archive.org/web/20180219054429/http://l.web.umkc.edu/lizhu/teaching/2016sp.video-communication/ref/mp4.pdf), and here is the [MP4 file format specification](https://github.com/OpenAnsible/rust-mp4/raw/master/docs/ISO_IEC_14496-14_2003-11-15.pdf), both defined as part of the ISO/IEC
14496 standard.

Also take a look at the [QuickTime MP4 specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFPreface/qtffPreface.html). It has a very clear explanation.

Answer (score 17):

"[ISO 14496-1 Media Format](http://xhelmboyx.tripod.com/formats/mp4-layout.txt)" gives a detailed description of the MP4 layout:

Answer (score 17):

The latest ISO doc is [ISO/IEC 14496-12:2015](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=68960). And you can download it at [Licence Agreement...](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c068960_ISO_IEC_14496-12_2015.zip) for free.