# In python, are the bytes of video/audio files split by frames with a certain character?

Tags: python, video

Say I have the bytes for a video file (unrealistic I know):

```
b'\x96\70a\u77\r44'
```

Yes, I know those are not bytes for a video file but whatever.

So, is there a specific byte (for example \x0b) that comes before every frame?

So like:

```
b'\firstframe\x0b\secondframe'
```

And so on, because I want to be able to split them.

Why? I am making a no-dependency python lib for vidoes/audio.

Comment: I guess you could have a look at some specifications of the video formats you're working with. Here are some links to MPEG-4 specifications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565068/mp4-file-format-specification

Comment: This question isn't a Python question, as far as I can tell... this seems to be a question about video/audio formats

Comment: True, but I need to know how to split it in python.